# Retrieving values from multiple tables using CakePHP model associations

Tags: cakephp, models

I have a ProductsController in which I am retrieving Products data and need to also retrieve the Category Name.  (Note: My Products table has only Category_ID in it), how can I do that using CakePHP model associations?

I have seen examples in which the ID of the main data table (in my case, Products table) is a Foreign Key in the Associated Table. However, my case slightly different in that the Category_ID (from the secondary table) is part of the Main table (Products table).

I am not able to retrieve the Category Name using CakePHP model config. Can you help?

My ProductsController is on Products table which has

```
ID
Prod_Name
Category_ID
....
```

My Categories table is like

```
ID
Cat_Name
```

In my ProductsController I want to retrieve Cat_Name for Products being retrieved.

Answer (score 6):

In your Product Model, use the association:

```
var $belongsTo = array(
    'Category' => array(
        'className' => 'Category',
        'foreignKey' => 'category_id',
        'conditions' => '',
        'fields' => '',
        'order' => ''
    )
);
```

When retrieving your Products data use `find` method:

```
$this->set('variable', $this->Product->find('all'));
```

Once its in your View, it is an array containing all the products and its category.
Like this:

```
<?php
foreach($variable as $itemInTable):
    echo 'Product:' . $itemInTable['Product']['Prod_Name'];
    echo 'Its Category:' . $itemInTable['Category']['Cat_Name'];
endforeach;
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

fzmaster's answer is correct.  When you have a foreign key in Table A that corresponds to an id in Table B, it is said that the Model A "belongs to" Model B.  At the same time, there could be an inverse relationship where Model B "has many" Model As.

The associations are fairly straightforward within that context and if you use the [Cake naming conventions](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/associations-linking-models-together.html), you can associate the models with minimal additional code:

```
class Product extends AppModel{
    var $belongsTo = array( 'Category' );
}

class Category extends AppModel{
    var $hasMany = array( 'Product' );
}
```

At that point, CakePHP's [`Model::Find()`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) method will automatically retrieve associated models unless you limit it with `$recursive` or by using the [`Containable`](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html) behavior.